# Extjs 4 - Save QR code locally as gif file

Tags: image, extjs, extjs4, qr-code

I'm using a nice extension for creating QR code of a given input - named **qrext.js**.

[see this link for more information](http://qrext.googlecode.com/git/qrext_readme.htm)

This extension creates Ext.Panel.panel with Ext.img element inside of it that shows the generated QR.

I want to have the ability to **save as...** as gif,  this QR gif image locally to my computer.

Is there a way to do that?

(I know that Ext.chart.Chart for example has the option to save locally to the comupter).

My example code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
            Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
                title : 'Text &amp; QR in a window',
                layout: 'fit',
                width : 250,
                height: 250,
                plain: true,
                border: 0,
                autoShow : true,
                defaults: {
                    padding: 10
                },
                items :[{
                    id: 'qr',
                    xtype : 'qrpanel',
                    textToEncode : 'this is the text that makes the QR...',
                    qrRenderMethod: 'gif',
                    qrNoClickHandler: true,
                    qrBlocksize : 6
                }]

});
```

And this is the result:

[image: QR Example]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/qrExample.gif))</sub>

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about this plugin but on the demo page, you can choose "gif" as preferred renderer and right click on the image and use "save as" option to store it on the computer. What you want to achieve? The same behavior with a dedicated download button?

Comment: WOW! Easier than I thought. Didn't even think of that option. It does the work for me. Thanks man!